# GoogleApi (Java) - User attribute "phones" cannot be set to empty

Tags: java, google-api

Im invoking Google API using the directory_v1-rev71-1.22.0 java library. Having integration with [Identity Management](https://github.com/Evolveum/connector-googleapps) solution Im able to add or remove values from user attribute "phones" via executing Directory.Users.Patch.

Unfortunately Im unable to delete the phones value completely. API [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/admin/directory/model/User.html#setPhones(java.lang.Object)) suggests using the null value as input in setPhones(java.lang.Object phones), but that did not help me - change is just not propagated. I also tried some other input types... e.g. empty ArrayList() and so on but to no good.

It seems to me there might be bug in the Google API since situations when phones attribute is not touched or nulled are both referred as null value.

Thanks for help,

Martin Lizner